# Hibernate5.2 StrategySelectionException when integrated with Spring4

Tags: spring, hibernate, sqlite

New to Spring4 and Hibernate and I am trying to integrate the two framework.Codes:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:META-INF/persistence_sqlite.properties")
public class DataConfig {
    @Autowired
    Environment environment;
    @Bean
    public DriverManagerDataSource dataSource(){
       DriverManagerDataSource driverManagerDataSource=new DriverManagerDataSource();
       driverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
       driverManagerDataSource.setUrl(environment.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
       return driverManagerDataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(){
        LocalSessionFactoryBean localSessionFactoryBean=new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        localSessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        localSessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("spittr.model");
        localSessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibernatePropertities());
       return localSessionFactoryBean;
    }


    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory){
       HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager=new HibernateTransactionManager();
       transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
       return transactionManager;
    }


    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslationPostProcessor(){
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    Properties hibernatePropertities(){
       Properties properties=new Properties();
       properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto",environment.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
       properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", environment.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
       properties.setProperty("hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers","true");
       properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql",environment.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
       return properties;
    }
}
```

`persistence_sqlite.properties`(no spelling errors,because I can locate classes concerned in IDE)

```
jdbc.driverClassName=org.sqlite.JDBC
jdbc.url=jdbc:sqlite:///home/stack/Documents/code/java/spittr/db/spittr.sqlite
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop
```

Junit4:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {DataConfig.class})
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class DataTest {
    @Autowired
    DataSource source;
    @Autowired
    Environment environment;
    @Test
    public void dataSourceTest(){
        Assert.assertNotNull(source);
    }
}
```

Root exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.selectStrategyImplementor(StrategySelectorImpl.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveDefaultableStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveDefaultableStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:139)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.constructDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:259)
    ... 73 more
```

I don't know what is wrong.Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I change the sqlite dialect class and now it works.